# How can a script check if a particular Docker container is running?

Tags: docker

I would like to have a shell script that checks if a particular container is running.

For example, I might want to start the container if it's not already running, or query some piece of information about it like what ports are exposed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`docker ps`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/) command takes a `-f` / `--filter` option to locate the desired container. To test if the container is running by name we might try

```sh
$ docker ps --filter "name=myapp" --filter "status=running"
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE               COMMAND   CREATED          STATUS          PORTS     NAMES
91959ed76e77   foo/barbaz:latest   "/init"   10 minutes ago   Up 10 minutes             myapp
```

If we just want the container ID, because we're going to pass it to another command like `docker exec`, we can use `-q` / `--quiet`:

```sh
$ docker ps --filter "name=myapp" --filter "status=running" --quiet
91959ed76e77
```

To just check whether it is running, we can see if the output is non-empty:

```sh
if [ -n "$(docker ps -f "name=myapp" -f "status=running" -q )" ]; then
    echo "the container is running!"
fi
```

Or if we want some other piece of information about it, `--format`:

```
$ docker ps -f "name=myapp" -f "status=running" --format "{{.Image}}"
foo/barbaz:latest
```

Answer (score 3):

You might also try using the [docker inspect](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/inspect/) command which works well with myapp as the container's name ... or the container's id :

```
if [ "$(docker inspect myapp --format '{{.State.Status}}')" = "running" ]; then
    echo "the container is running!"
fi
```